# Copy rows only if cells are not blank in selected columns

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns, copy-paste

Below code (Code One) is currently working fine, where selected columns are copy & pasted with single criteria in Column A.

However, I am trying to add another condition, where excel will not copy cells if Columns N to R are blank. I tried writing Code Two (below) but getting Run-time error '9' Subscript out of Range.

Can I please get some assistance in changing Code Two so it will filter the columns correctly.

Code One

```
Dim i As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim iTarget As Long

With Worksheets("Okay")

    iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "Welcome" Then
            iTarget = iTarget + 1
            .Cells(i, "B").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "C").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "D").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("C" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "E").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("D" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "F").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("F" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("G" & iTarget + 1).Value = "How"
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("H" & iTarget + 1).Value = "Are"
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("I" & iTarget + 1).Value = "You"
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("J" & iTarget + 1).Value = "Okay"
            .Cells(i, "N").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("K" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "O").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("L" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "P").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("M" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "Q").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("N" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "R").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("O" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i

End With
```

Code Two

```
Dim i As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim iTarget As Long

With Worksheets("Okay")

    iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "Welcome" Then
        If .Cells(i, "N").Value <> "" Then
        If .Cells(i, "O").Value <> "" Then
        If .Cells(i, "P").Value <> "" Then
        If .Cells(i, "Q").Value <> "" Then
        If .Cells(i, "R").Value <> "" Then
            iTarget = iTarget + 1
            .Cells(i, "B").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "C").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "D").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("C" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "E").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("D" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "F").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("F" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("G" & iTarget + 1).Value = "Hello"
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("H" & iTarget + 1).Value = "How"
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("I" & iTarget + 1).Value = "Are"
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("J" & iTarget + 1).Value = "You"
            .Cells(i, "N").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("K" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "O").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("L" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "P").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("M" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "Q").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("N" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "R").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("O" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(i, "G").Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("P" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
    Next i

End With
```

Comment: Just .AutoFilter for columns N:R not blank then copy the filtered data across. Asked and answered **numerous** times on this site.

Comment: And, if @Jeeped's suggestion doesn't help, at least tell us **which** line gives the error in your current code.

Comment: Auto filter won't work unless i add another helper column in the data I am trying to copy. If any one of the five columns (Column N-R) are populated, i would still have to copy and paste. The line I am getting error is the first pasting row >> Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: FWIW - Code 2 works for me, no errors.

Comment: And I strongly recommend you get rid of the copy/paste - `.Cells(i, "B").Copy` `Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` can be written as `Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & iTarget + 1).Value = .Cells(i, "B").Value`, which avoids using the clipboard and thus improves speed and reduces errors caused by users copy/pasting while your macro is running.

Comment: Do you have a worksheet named "Sheet7"?  (If your Code 1 works, I assume you do, but that is the only cause of a subscript out of range on the `Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` line.)

Comment: Thanks YowE3K, Can you please post both into the answer of the question so I can close this case.

Comment: What was the error?  Just the missing sheet?

Comment: I think so, I couldn't find out the reason so I used my backup file and added the five "if"s again and it worked, something must have been wrong on my working file. I also made changes per your suggestion re past special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a "subscript out of range" error on the line

```
Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & iTarget + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

then the most likely reason (or, I think, the only reason) is that you don't have a worksheet called "Sheet7".

---

Note:  You can improve your code by not using Copy/Paste.  Copy/Paste is slow, and it can also lead to issues if your users perform another manual copy/paste in some other application while they are waiting for your macro to run.  Try this slightly refactored code:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim iTarget As Long
iTarget = 1 ' initialise value to avoid lots of "+ 1"s

With Worksheets("Okay")    
    iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "Welcome" Then
        If .Cells(i, "N").Value <> "" Then
        If .Cells(i, "O").Value <> "" Then
        If .Cells(i, "P").Value <> "" Then
        If .Cells(i, "Q").Value <> "" Then
        If .Cells(i, "R").Value <> "" Then
            iTarget = iTarget + 1
            'Set 4 columns at once
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & iTarget).Resize(1, 4).Value = .Cells(i, "B").Resize(1, 4).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("F" & iTarget).Value = .Cells(i, "F").Value
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("G" & iTarget).Value = "Hello"
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("H" & iTarget).Value = "How"
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("I" & iTarget).Value = "Are"
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("J" & iTarget).Value = "You"
            'Set 5 columns at once
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("K" & iTarget).Resize(1, 5).Value = .Cells(i, "N").Resize(1, 5).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("P" & iTarget).Value = .Cells(i, "G").Value
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
    Next i    
End With
```